# Not sure how to convert string to usable discord data

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a system for my discord bot to store data about a message in a text file. To do this the message information turns into a string. The problem is I get an error when I am trying to use this data. For example, when I try to do message.remove_reaction I get this error message:

```
File "main.py", line 195, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await message.remove_reaction("✅", payload.member)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove_reaction'
```

I am converting the text file into a list and converting it back to a variable. For example, message = file_data[5]. Here's the code that extracts the data from the text files.

```
for x in fileNames:
    f = open(x, "r+")
    messageid = f.readline()
    #creates list if message id match is found
    if (int(messageid) == int(payload.message_id)):
      p = open(x, "r+")
      global file_name
      file_name = p
      for x in p:
        file = x.rstrip('\n')
        file_data.append(file)
      break
  print(file_data)
  #assigning variables from list
  messageid = file_data[0]
  in_embed = file_data[2]
  game_actual = file_data[3]
  goal_actual = file_data[4]
  message = file_data[5]
  names = []
  #stores member information onto seperate list
  for x in range(6,len(file_data)):
    names.append(x)
```

The list before turning them into variables:

```
['814375931497021490', '811857283771662340', "<Message id=814375932051456000 channel=<TextChannel id=811857283771662340 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=811857283771662338> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=810761971979911188 name='CockGobbler' discriminator='2337' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=811857283771662337 name='Bot Test 2' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>", 'game2', '2', "<Message id=814375931497021490 channel=<TextChannel id=811857283771662340 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=811857283771662338> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=810761971979911188 name='CockGobbler' discriminator='2337' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=811857283771662337 name='Bot Test 2' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not show how you are converting the `Message` to string or what you are trying to do with it, but generally I would suggest you to not convert it to string.

A better approach would be to save the `Message.content` which is already a string of the real content of the message, in case you want to access the content. Or you could save the `Message.id` and when you need to get your `Message` object to use a function like:

```py
await message.remove_reaction
```

What you would do is simply retrieving the `Message` object (or `PartialMessage` in this case):

```py
my_message = get_partial_message(message_ID)
await my_message.remove_reaction("✅", payload.member)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing and reading everything as strings, when they should really be read as specific classes as defined by `discord.py`. You have a few options to solve your issue.

1. [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Define a picklable class. Make a class that has attributes that align with whichever data you want to get from the message. You can then `dump` that object, meaning turn it into a file, and then `load` it, meaning turn it back into usable python code.

2. Manually turn your `file_data` into the correct objects

Go through the [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) documentation, and the [Message source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/message.py), and check what kind of type every part of the message needs to be before trying to use them.